# PHP mysql join tables return all results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having a bit of difficulty working something out. I have the follow 2 tables:

**fixture**
id, hometeam, awayteam, datetime

**feed**
id, homeodd, drawodd, awayodd fixtureid

In the feed table fixtureid is the same as the id column in the fixture table. the issue I'm having is only 10 fixtures have a homeodd or drawodd or awayodd but I still want to show all the fixtures and just show the data from homeodd/drawodd/awayodd if its available.

So far I have got it to the following statement but its only pulling through matches that have a feed fixtureid matched to it:

```
SELECT fixture.id, hometeam, awayteam, datetime, feed.fixtureid AS fix_id, feed.homeodd, feed.drawodd, feed.awayodd FROM fixture JOIN feed feed ON feed.fixtureid = fixture.id
```

Like I said this only returns 10 options instead of the 360 available, as it looks like its just pulling out data that has a match in the feed table.

Any ideas how I could achieve all the fixtures and just show the data if its in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - this will give you all the rows on the 'left' table, and NULLs where there is no corresponding row in the 'right' table:

```
SELECT fixture.id, hometeam, awayteam, datetime, feed.fixtureid AS fix_id, 
       feed.homeodd, feed.drawodd, feed.awayodd 
FROM fixture 
LEFT JOIN feed feed ON (feed.fixtureid = fixture.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fixture.id, hometeam, awayteam, datetime, feed.fixtureid AS fix_id, feed.homeodd, feed.drawodd, feed.awayodd 
FROM fixture 
    LEFT JOIN feed ON (feed.fixtureid = fixture.id)
```